# how to pass a subvector of a 2d vector in a function in c++

Tags: c++

```
void Solution::rotate(vector<vector<int> > &A) {
   int n= A.size();
int temp[n];
for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
{
    temp[j]=A[n-1][j];
}
   for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
   {
       A[n-1][i]=A[n-i-1][n-1];
       A[n-i-1][n-1] = A[0][n-i-1];
       A[0][n-i-1]=A[i][0];
       A[i][0]=temp[i];
       //A[i+1][0]=A[n-1][i+1];
  }
}
```

I want to call the function again and pass the subarray of original array with starting point as (1,1) of the array and the end point as (n-2,n-2) of the array.
Is it possible to get it done without creating a new vector, i mean just by passing some pointer to the function?

Comment: Easiest (and fastest, i.e. optimized) way of doing it is to use a flat `vector<int>` and map from 2D to 1D and vice-versa.

Comment: If you want to slice in both dimensions, you could simply pass the first and last index for every dimension and use this to edit the vector that you pass *by reference*.

Comment: passing the limiting dimensions as parameter with the vector should get the job done.

Comment: I have a function that can create a sub vector and copy the data you want in it, but **it require to create a new vector** ( in fact, several new vectors ), and make copy of the data. Do you want it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to look at the submatrix or edit a bounded region in place, make a viewer. The viewer doesn't do anything but restrict the the area of the matrix you are allowed to look at. There is no copying and little extra memory used. This is great if you have, for example, a huge picture and you want to view and manipulate 8x8 element areas.

If you need a new matrix of the given view, teach the viewer to create a new matrix based on the view. There is copying involved in this case, but when you want a copy, copying's hard to avoid.

To demonstrate, first I'm going to wander off the beaten path a bit. If you want this to be fast (and who doesn't want fast?) don't use `vector<vector>`. A `vector` is guaranteed to be contiguous in memory, but when you have vectors of vectors that guarantee goes out the window and this leads to poor spatial locality and typically to poor cache usage.

Here is a simple example of a Matrix class that is a bit easier to work with and is all one memory chunk so it tends to be more cache friendly.

```
// wrapping class for 2D matrixes
class Matrix
{
private:
    size_t rows, columns; // large, unsigned datatype. Don't want negative
                          // indices, so why allow them?
    std::vector<int> matrix; // 1D vector. Simple and easy to handle.
                             // also often much faster than vector of vectors
                             // due to improved spatial locality helping
                             // predictability of data access
public:
    // build zero-filled Matrix
    Matrix(size_t numrows, size_t numcols) :
            rows(numrows), columns(numcols), matrix(rows * columns)
    {
    }

    // 2D to 1D mapping accessor
    int & operator()(size_t row, size_t column)
    {
        // check bounds here
        return matrix[row * columns + column];
    }

    // 2D to 1D mapping accessor for constant Matrix
    int operator()(size_t row, size_t column) const
    {
        // check bounds here
        return matrix[row * columns + column];
    }

    // dimension accessors
    size_t getRows() const
    {
        return rows;
    }
    size_t getColumns() const
    {
        return columns;
    }
};
```

Now that we have a faster, nicely contained Matrix class we can make a really simple `MatrixView` class.

```
class MatrixView
{
    size_t mStartRow;       // view offset in row
    size_t mStartColumn;    // view offset in column
    size_t mRows;           // number of viewed rows
    size_t mColumns;        // number of viewed columns
    Matrix & mMat;          // viewed Matrix

public:
    // using start and endpoints in this constructor. A more ideologically correct 
    // constructor would behave the same as the standard library and take offset 
    // and length as parameters.
    MatrixView(size_t startrow,
               size_t startcolumn,
               size_t endrow, 
               size_t endcolumn,
               Matrix & mat):
                   mStartRow(startrow),
                   mStartColumn(startcolumn),
                   mRows(endrow - startrow),
                   mColumns(endcolumn - startcolumn),
                   mMat(mat)
    {
        //ensure dimensions make sense
        if (startrow > endrow ||
            startcolumn > endcolumn ||
            mRows > mat.getRows() ||
            mColumns > mat.getColumns())
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Bad MatrixView dimensions");
        }
    }
    int & operator()(size_t row, size_t column)
    {
        // check bounds here if you want to
        // look at the source matrix plus offsets
        return mMat(row+mStartRow, column+mStartColumn);
    }

    // 2D to 1D mapping accessor for constant Matrix
    int operator()(size_t row, size_t column) const
    {
        // check bounds here if you want to
        return mMat(row+mStartRow, column+mStartColumn);
    }

    // dimension accessors
    size_t getRows() const
    {
        return mRows;
    }
    size_t getColumns() const
    {
        return mColumns;
    }

    // build a new Matrix based on this view
    Matrix clone()
    {
        Matrix result(mRows, mColumns);
        for (size_t row = 0; row < mRows; ++row)
        {
            for (size_t col = 0; col < mColumns; ++col)
            {
                result(row, col) = mMat(row+mStartRow, col+mStartColumn);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

And an example of using this sucker:

```
// stream formatters
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const Matrix & mat)
{
    for (size_t row = 0; row < mat.getRows(); ++row)
    {
        for (size_t col = 0; col < mat.getColumns(); ++col)
        {
            std::cout << std::setw(5) << mat(row, col);
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    return out;
}
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const MatrixView & mat)
{
    for (size_t row = 0; row < mat.getRows(); ++row)
    {
        for (size_t col = 0; col < mat.getColumns(); ++col)
        {
            std::cout << std::setw(5) << mat(row, col);
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    return out;
}


int main()
{
    Matrix one(6, 6); // make 6x6 matrix
    int count = 0;

    // set inputs to make errors really stand out
    for (size_t row = 0; row < one.getRows(); ++row)
    {
        for (size_t col = 0; col < one.getColumns(); ++col)
        {
            one(row, col) = count++;
        }
    }

    // print initial matrix
    std::cout << one << '\n';

    // make a view of matrix that leaves off the outside.
    MatrixView view(1,1,5,5, one);

    // print the view
    std::cout << view << '\n';

    // get a clone of the view we can pass into a function 
    Matrix clone = view.clone();

    // and print the clone
    std::cout << clone << '\n';
}
```

Comment: In my exoerience, better matrix view has a pointer, a width, height, and stride.  Don't bind it to only wrapping a matrix.